# If I change Windows 8 to do a factory reset from the hard disk as opposed to optical media, will this work every time?

Tags: windows-8, factory-defaults

There is a guide [here](http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/18052-refresh-reset-windows-8-without-installation-disk.html) to preform a full reset of Windows 8 without having to use optical media.

My question is, if I follow this guide once, does this mean that optical media will not be required for any resets done in the future, or will I have to do this each time?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It means that optical media will not be required for a reset, *as long as the reset information installed on the hard disk is not changed*.

The process essentially copies the data from the optical media to your hard disk, and then uses that for the reset, instead of optical media. This will work as long as the copy on the hard disk is not changed. So it will probably work if you want to reset because you messed up your configuration. However, if you reset because of a virus or malware, or because you had to format your disk, you will still need the optical media.